# JSON file parsing to database in Java web program

Tags: java, json, html-parsing

I have a big JSON file as below.

```
[{"id":0,"name":"Mrs. Tess Goyette","priceRange":{"min":86,"max":87},"requirements":["close to transport","internet","bath","gym"]},..
```

Like wise there are 999 items like that. I want to send this data to MySQL database. Also 
do some transactions with it. there is one more file like this which possess 40 hotel names and data called accommodation.

I am not able to parse this file using java. Can anybody help? I tried to create one JSON object and array in it, but failed.`enter code here`

Any help is appreciated.

yes sure i have tried to code something like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try {

                        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

            InputStream is = hoteldemo.class.getResourceAsStream("accommodation.json");


            String jsonTxt = IOUtils.toString(is); 
            JSON json = JSONSerializer.toJSON(jsonTxt);

            JSONObject json1 = (JSONObject)JSONSerializer.toJSON(jsonTxt); 
            JSONObject json2= json1.getJSONObject("menu");

              double id = json2.getDouble("id");
            String name = json2.getString("name");
            int price=json2.getInt("price");

            JSONArray jarray=json2.getJSONArray("attributes");
            //JSONArray jarray1=json1.getJSONArray("capacity");

           int a= json2.size();
            for(int i=0;i<json2.size();i++)
            {
            System.out.println("The id is "+ json2.getDouble("id"));
            System.out.println("The name is "+ json2.getString("name"));
            System.out.println("The price is "+ json2.getInt("price"));
         System.out.println("the size of object is" + a);

            }
         /*   for(int i=0;i<jarray.size();i++)
            {
                System.out.println("This is ameneities id is " + jarray.getString(i));
            }
            for(int j=0;j<jarray1.size();j++)
            {
                System.out.println("This is ameneities id is " + jarray1.getString(j));

            }*/


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    }
```

but it is giving me just one object like only first id and next id is not accessible on the for loop.

Comment: Please show us your code and tell us [what you have already tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: I have done something like this.

Comment: *"I have done something like this."*  I nominate that for the most meaningless (and therefore pointless) comment of the day. 1) Tell us exactly, not 'something like' what you tried.  2) 'this' *what*?  When we asked what you had tried, we meant 'what code?'.  While 'this' is a Java keyword, it is not code.

Comment: I guess, he added the code in his question. But yes the comment is indeed deceptive ;)

Comment: Which library are you using for manipulating the JSON? [Google GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), [json.org](http://json.org/java/)?

Comment: File name is accomodation.json

Comment: and the price renamed as pricerange

Comment: and attributes renamed as requirments. i hope this makes sense.

Comment: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils,
org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser

Comment: You forgot the add the actuall error message you are getting.

Comment: aftter executing this code i am able to get only first id as output ie id:0 where as i want to access all 999 items ie the id , name,price, requirments for all 999 travellers.can u suggest me any changes in the code to get this output.

Answer (score 0):

When handling JSON formatted data, the first thing I usually like to do is not handle JSON.  I often prefer to populate some good old POJOs, and then proceed with any business logic.  To map the JSON to a Java data structure, my preference is to use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org).  Following is an example of using Jackson to deserialize the example JSON from the original question.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonMethod;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonFoo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().setVisibility(JsonMethod.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);

    List<AccomodationRequest> requests = mapper.readValue(new File("accommodation.json"), mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, AccomodationRequest.class));
    System.out.println(requests);

    for (AccomodationRequest request : requests)
    {
      System.out.println("----");
      System.out.println("id is " + request.id);
      System.out.println("name is " + request.name);
    }
  }
}

class AccomodationRequest
{
  int id;
  String name;
  PriceRange priceRange;
  List<String> requirements;

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return String.format("AccomodationRequest: id=%d, name=%s, priceRange=%s, requirements=%s", id, name, priceRange, requirements);
  }
}

class PriceRange
{
  int min;
  int max;

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return String.format("PriceRange: min=%d, max=%d", min, max);
  }
}
```

Comment: which library you are using for objectmapper class. eclipse is not detecting that class for 1.4.2 jar file